# How to import the last row from array of excel files to another excel using openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, openpyxl

I have a list of excel files with similar last row. It contains private information about client (his name, surname, phone). Each excel file correspond to each client. I need to make one excel file with all data about every client.
I decide to do it automatically, so looked to openpyxl library.
I wrote such code, but it doesn't work correctly.

In my test directory I have three files.

```
import openpyxl
import os
import glob
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl import Workbook
import openpyxl.styles
from openpyxl.cell import get_column_letter

def get_range(file, new_file):

    prize_sheet = prize_info.active
    sheet = f.active
    for row_num in range (1, len(file_array_reciever)):
        for col_num in range (3,sheet.max_column):
            prize_sheet.cell(row = row_num, column = col_num).value = sheet.cell(row = sheet.max_row, column = col_num).value

    return prize_info.save("Ex.xlsx")



#path to test files
path_kit = 'prize_input/kit'

#creating single document
prize_info = Workbook()

file_array_reciever = []

for file in glob.glob(os.path.join(path_kit, '*.xlsx')):
    file_array_reciever.append(file)


for file in glob.glob(os.path.join(path_kit, '*.xlsx')):
    file_array_reciever.append(file)
    f = load_workbook(filename = file)
    get_range(f,prize_info)
```

I think I have problem in my loop, because in output file I get three identical rows from first excel file

Answer (score 0):

The function `get_range()` will overwrite the existing rows.

You should be able to use `ws.rows[-1]` to get the last row from any sheet. Something like

```
for f in file_array_receiver:
    sheet = f.active
    prize_sheet.append(f.rows[-1][:3])
```

Might be what you're looking for.